# Encoding bitmap to video using MediaCodec and Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-mediacodec

```
class BitmapToVideoEncoder(private val mCallback: IBitmapToVideoEncoderCallback) {
    private var mOutputFile: File? = null
    private var mEncodeQueue: Queue<Bitmap?> = ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Bitmap?>()
    private var mediaCodec: MediaCodec? = null
    private var mediaMuxer: MediaMuxer? = null
    private val mFrameSync = Any()
    private var mNewFrameLatch: CountDownLatch? = null
    private var mGenerateIndex = 0
    private var mTrackIndex = 0
    private var mNoMoreFrames = false
    private var mAbort = false

    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    fun startEncoding(width: Int, height: Int, outputFile: File) {
        println("DEBUG: Start Encoding")
        mWidth = width
        mHeight = height
        mOutputFile = outputFile
        val outputFileString: String = try {
            outputFile.canonicalPath
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e(
                TAG,
                "Unable to get path for $outputFile"
            )
            return
        }
        val codecInfo = selectCodec()
        if (codecInfo == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find an appropriate codec for $MIME_TYPE")
            return
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "found codec: " + codecInfo.name)
        val colorFormat: Int = try {
            selectColorFormat(codecInfo)
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible
        }
        mediaCodec = try {
            MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecInfo.name)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create MediaCodec " + e.message)
            return
        }
        val mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, mWidth, mHeight)
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE)
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE)
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat)
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, I_FRAME_INTERVAL)
        mediaCodec!!.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)
        mediaCodec!!.start()
        mediaMuxer = try {
            MediaMuxer(outputFileString, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MediaMuxer creation failed. " + e.message)
            return
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Initialization complete. Starting encoder...")
        GlobalScope.launch {
            try {
                encode()
            } catch(e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                println("DEBUG: ${e.localizedMessage}")
            }
        }
    }

    fun stopEncoding() {
//
    }

    fun queueFrame(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
        if (mediaCodec == null || mediaMuxer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to queue frame. Encoding not started")
            return
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Queueing frame")
        mEncodeQueue.add(bitmap)
        synchronized(mFrameSync) {
            if (mNewFrameLatch != null && mNewFrameLatch!!.count > 0) {
                mNewFrameLatch!!.countDown()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun encode() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Encoder started")
        while (true) {
            if (mNoMoreFrames && mEncodeQueue.size == 0) break
            var bitmap = mEncodeQueue.poll()
            if (bitmap == null) {
                synchronized(mFrameSync) {
                    mNewFrameLatch = CountDownLatch(1)
                }
                try {
                    mNewFrameLatch!!.await()
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    println("DEBUG: (Encode) ${e.localizedMessage}")
                }
                bitmap = mEncodeQueue.poll()
            }
            if (bitmap == null) continue
            val byteConvertFrame = getNV21(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, bitmap)
            val TIMEOUT_USEC: Long = 500000
            val inputBufIndex = mediaCodec!!.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC)
            val ptsUsec = computePresentationTime(mGenerateIndex.toLong())
            if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                val inputBuffer = mediaCodec!!.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex)
                inputBuffer!!.clear()
                inputBuffer.put(byteConvertFrame)
                val presentationTimeUs = computePresentationTime(mGenerateIndex.toLong())
                mediaCodec!!.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, byteConvertFrame.size, presentationTimeUs, 0)
                mGenerateIndex++
            }
            val mBufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
            val encoderStatus = mediaCodec!!.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC)
            if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                // no output available yet
                Log.e(TAG, "No output from encoder available")
            } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                // not expected for an encoder
                val newFormat = mediaCodec!!.outputFormat
                mTrackIndex = mediaMuxer!!.addTrack(newFormat)
                mediaMuxer!!.start()
            } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                Log.e(
                    TAG,
                    "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: $encoderStatus"
                )
            } else if (mBufferInfo.size != 0) {
                val encodedData = mediaCodec!!.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus)
                if (encodedData == null) {
                    Log.e(
                        TAG,
                        "encoderOutputBuffer $encoderStatus was null"
                    )
                } else {
                    encodedData.position(mBufferInfo.offset)
                    encodedData.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size)
                    mediaMuxer!!.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mBufferInfo)
                    mediaCodec!!.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false)
                }
            }
        }
        release()
        if (mAbort) {
            mOutputFile!!.delete()
        } else {
            mCallback.onEncodingComplete(mOutputFile)
        }
    }

    private fun release() {
        if (mediaCodec != null) {
            mediaCodec!!.stop()
            mediaCodec!!.release()
            mediaCodec = null
            Log.d(TAG, "RELEASE CODEC")
        }
        if (mediaMuxer != null) {
            mediaMuxer!!.stop()
            mediaMuxer!!.release()
            mediaMuxer = null
            Log.d(TAG, "RELEASE MUXER")
        }
    }

    private fun getNV21(inputWidth: Int, inputHeight: Int, bitmap: Bitmap): ByteArray {
        val argb = IntArray(inputWidth * inputHeight)
        bitmap.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight)

        val yuv = ByteArray(inputWidth * inputHeight * 3 / 2)
        var yIndex = 0
        var uvIndex = inputWidth * inputHeight
        var index = 0

        for (j in 0 until inputHeight) {
            for (i in 0 until inputWidth) {
                val r = (argb[index] and 0xff0000) shr 16
                val g = (argb[index] and 0xff00) shr 8
                val b = argb[index] and 0xff

                // Y channel
                yuv[yIndex++] = ((66 * r + 129 * g + 25 * b + 128) shr 8 + 16).toByte()

                // UV channel
                if (j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0) {
                    yuv[uvIndex++] = ((-38 * r - 74 * g + 112 * b + 128) shr 8 + 128).toByte()
                    yuv[uvIndex++] = ((112 * r - 94 * g - 18 * b + 128) shr 8 + 128).toByte()
                }

                index++
            }
        }
        return yuv
    }

    private fun computePresentationTime(frameIndex: Long): Long {
        return 132 + frameIndex * 1000000 / FRAME_RATE
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = BitmapToVideoEncoder::class.java.simpleName
        private const val MIME_TYPE = "video/avc" // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
        private var mWidth = 0
        private var mHeight = 0
        private const val BIT_RATE = 16000000
        private const val FRAME_RATE = 30 // Frames per second
        private const val I_FRAME_INTERVAL = 1
        private fun selectCodec(): MediaCodecInfo? {
            return MediaCodecList(MediaCodecList.ALL_CODECS).codecInfos.firstOrNull { codecInfo ->
                codecInfo.isEncoder && codecInfo.supportedTypes.any { it.equals(MIME_TYPE, ignoreCase = true) }
            }
        }

        private fun selectColorFormat(codecInfo: MediaCodecInfo): Int {
            codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(MIME_TYPE).colorFormats.forEach { colorFormat ->
                if (isRecognizedFormat(colorFormat)) {
                    return colorFormat
                }
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported color format")
        }

        private fun isRecognizedFormat(colorFormat: Int): Boolean {
            return colorFormat == CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using cameraX, I'm analysing the frames and converting to bitmap and wanted to encode the bitmap frames to a video for the user to watch at the end. When the video file is returned to me it looks corrupted. But it's working (kinda), when I wave my hand in front of the camera when recording, a distorted hand is visible.

I've tried changing the size of the video, I'm expecting the video to be returned properly

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).